# I want to add Sub Total using SAQL Query

Tags: saql

| Region | Sector | Notes | Count of Rows |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| America | FI | Client Choice | 2 |
|  |  | Entry | 8 |
|  |  | **Sub Total | 10** |
|  | MI | Rotation | 45 |
|  |  | Data Source | 30 |
|  |  | **Sub Total | 75** |
|  | **Sub Total |  | 85** |

I have the above table which shows Sub Total by Notes and Sub Total by Region. I want to write a SAQL query in which I could see just "**SUB TOTAL BY REGION**" in the final output in compare table. (example just I want to see Sub Total as 85 in the output table)

Comment: Hey, have you made an attempt to write this SAQL query? Or have you just got a requirement and want someone from Salesforce Stack Exchange to implement it for you? Sorry to say, but this is not the idea of this site.

Comment: @FelixvanHove yes, I have implemented it.

Comment: q = load "Issuance1";
q = group q by rollup ('Region','Sector','SalesComments');
q = foreach q generate case when grouping('Region') == 1 then "Total" else 'Region' end as 'Region', 
case when grouping('Sector') == 1 then "Subtotal" else 'Sector' end as 'Sector',
case when grouping('SalesComments') == 1 then "" else 'SalesComments' end as 'SalesComments',
count() as 'count';
q = order q by ('Region' asc, 'Sector' asc,'SalesComments' asc);
q = limit q 2000;

Comment: But the above query doesn't give me the right output

Answer (score 0):

```
q = load "Issuance1";
q = group q by rollup ('Region','Sector','SalesComments');
q = foreach q generate case when grouping('Region') == 1 then "Total" else 'Region' end as 'Region', 
case when grouping('Sector') == 1 then "Subtotal" else 'Sector' end as 'Sector',
case when grouping('SalesComments') == 1 then "" else 'SalesComments' end as 'SalesComments',
count() as 'count';
q = filter q by ('SalesComments' != "" or 'Sector' =="Subtotal");
q = filter q by 'Region' != "Total";
q = order q by ('Region' asc, 'Sector' asc,'SalesComments' asc);
q = limit q 2000;
```

This is the answer